# Having problems connecting to something with php/curl mix

Tags: php, curl

code:

```
<?php
$str = '';
$max = mb_strlen("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", '8bit') - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 11; ++$i) {
    $str .= "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random_int(0, $max)];
}

try {
    $ch = curl_init();


    if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://youtube.com/watch?v=".$str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //curl_setopt(/* ... */);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (FALSE === $content)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

    if(strpos($content, 'unavailable') !==FALSE) {
        header("Refresh:0");
    } else {
        echo "<iframe src=\"https://youtube.com/embed/".$str."\" />";
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'An error occured when getting video information: #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

}

?>
```

Errors returned:

> Fatal error: An error occured when getting video information: #7:
>   Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:4017:807::200e: Network is unreachable
>   in /srv/disk15/2498627/www/randomvideofinder.xyz/index.php on line 45

website I'm trying to use it on: http://randomvideofinder.xyz/

I'm quite a rookie at this. so it would be nice if any of you can help. thank you.

Comment: Which line in your code corresponds to line 45?

Comment: @Nic3500        line 45 is "E_USER_ERROR);"

Comment: That "Failed to connect to" is a network problem, and this **2a00:1450:4017:807::200e:** is the IpV6 it is trying to use.  Are you able to run commands like ping, telnet, traceroute, ... from the source server?  Something is blocking the curl at the network level.

Comment: I cant do any of those commands, its on a free hosting plan. any way to force it into using ipv4?

Comment: Since it is on a free hosting plan, you have no control on name resolution, so no if they prefer V6, you are stuck with that.  But that is not a problem.  From your PHP code you could try to run the commands using system or exec.  If they allow it...  The hosting provider might simply block connections originating from their servers, and you would have no control on that.  Check their usage policies and/or contact support.

Comment: SELinux permissions? FirewallD settings? In any recent Linux flavor, these are enforced by default during install. Are you trying to return this information to a directory that does not have SELinux permissions.  If you can access the web, then it's not a network issue.  Just try: ping google.com from the command line.  If successful, then you likely are trying to get curl to run in a directory that is not authorized by SELinux, or the port you're using is blocked in either or both.